# Are electric stove/burner elements/coils interchangeable

Tags: stove, range

Are the electric burners/elements/coils for electric stoves interchangeable between brands? This is aside from the "big" and "small" diameters.

They appear to have the same connectors ends, but I'm wondering if there are any differences, either in connector design, element resistance, or other aspects I haven't considered.

Since the connectors on the elements appear the same, it is tempting to use them in any stove without a second thought. The cause for a second thought is [a disintegrated connector in another question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/200904/what-is-this-electric-burner-connector/), and whether it was simply normal wear and tear or if an out-of-spec element could be a reason. I know elements from an older now-discarded GE range were kept and used in a newer Whirlpool range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes and no. Some brands have unique connectors but many are generic.  I would verify the wattage is the same and the fit is the same as long as those items are the same there should be no issues.

The connector issue could be a cheap one was used not high temp. When I repair stove wiring I use 900f degree connectors the standard ones you would get at a big box store are usually only rated for 90c max some only 75c these get loose with heat and start arcing until no contact area is left.

Comment: How can the wattage be verified? I could measure resistance if this is supposed to be standardized. As for the connector, it is the original. I believe there was arcing and was maybe loose. Heavy pots end up moving the element, because the element supports are not very supportive on this range.

Comment: Yes cal rod is resistance based. The last one I measured was a 6” , I purchased another one online I want to say it was 65 ohms  it was within a few ohms of the one I had and worked perfectly I would say +-10 would be fine.

Comment: I measured the two 6" elements at 37 and 46 ohms, and the two 8" elements at 21 and 25 ohms.

Comment: Ok 37 and 46 are within 10 ohms and if those are originals 35-55 range will be just fine. if much higher it won’t get as hot if two low it will get two hot and may damage the control (two much current)  they are almost always slightly different even from the same MFG. So a few ohms is no big deal.